# Intent is not starting a new Activity

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You taped!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     try {
         startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FuelChoiceActivity.class));
     }catch (Exception e){
         System.out.println(e);
     }
 }
```

Here is my code. I've added the new activity to my manifest.xml. The try/catch block is not returning any exeption. When i press the button the toast is executed and displayed but the page is not changing. This onClickListener is inside an adapter method 'getView'so it can be obtained by any button generated from the adapter. I tried putting other events and they work! The only thing that doesn't is going to the new Activity.

here is my log when i debug and click on a button:

```
 
D/AbsListView: reportScrollStateChange: newState = 0, mLastScrollState = 0, mOnScrollListener = null, mScrollY = 0, mTouchMode = -1, mFirstPosition = 0
V/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{2c1d62f0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@32487069 {com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper/com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper.MainActivity}}
D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@32487069
D/AbsListView: onWindowFocusChanged: hasWindowFocus=false, this=com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper.ExpandableHeightGridView{1dffd375 VFED.VC. .F...... 8,0-472,965 #7f0c0053 app:id/mygridview}
D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb884d518) (w:177 h:66 s:192 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb884d518) (w:177 h:66 s:192 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb884d518) (w:177 h:66 s:192 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
V/ActivityThread: Handling launch of ActivityRecord{1ff7b407 token=android.os.BinderProxy@19bbf934 {com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper/com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper.FuelChoiceActivity}}
V/ActivityThread: ActivityRecord{1ff7b407 token=android.os.BinderProxy@19bbf934 {com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper/com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper.FuelChoiceActivity}}: app=android.app.Application@a0dbe1c, appName=com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper, pkg=com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper, comp={com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper/com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper.FuelChoiceActivity}, dir=/data/app/com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper-1/base.apk
D/ActivityThread: ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{1ff7b407 token=android.os.BinderProxy@19bbf934 {com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper/com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper.FuelChoiceActivity}}
D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY_FINISHING handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@19bbf934
V/ActivityThread: Performing resume of ActivityRecord{2c1d62f0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@32487069 {com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper/com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper.MainActivity}}
D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{2c1d62f0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@32487069 {com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper/com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper.MainActivity}}
V/ActivityThread: Resume ActivityRecord{2c1d62f0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@32487069 {com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper/com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper.MainActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
V/ActivityThread: Resuming ActivityRecord{2c1d62f0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@32487069 {com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper/com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper.MainActivity}} with isForward=true
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{dfe4562 com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper/com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1d6eaa25 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-480,782}
V/ActivityThread: Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{2c1d62f0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@32487069 {com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper/com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper.MainActivity}}
D/ActivityThread: ACT-RESUME_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@32487069
D/AbsListView: onWindowFocusChanged: hasWindowFocus=true, this=com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper.ExpandableHeightGridView{1dffd375 VFED.VC. .F...... 8,0-472,965 #7f0c0053 app:id/mygridview}
V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: com.example.stamatis.redhotpepper.ExpandableHeightGridView{1dffd375 VFED.VC. .F...... 8,0-472,965 #7f0c0053 app:id/mygridview} softInputMode=272 first=false flags=#1810100
D/ActivityThread: ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@19bbf934
D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb884d518) (w:177 h:66 s:192 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
```

Thanks for reading and your time. I would appreciate thoughts.

Comment: Do you get any loggers in the onCreate of FuelChoiceActivity

Comment: we could have a better idea of the problem if we had acccess to FuelChoiceActivity

Comment: FuelChoiceActivity has only the basic onCreate and stuff. If i launch it as main it works. the only deference is that my main activity extends Activity and the FuelChoiceActivity extends  AppCompatActivity. No logs on the second

Comment: The problem was that the second activity wasnt extending the same class. I changed the inheritance to be the same and it worked. Thanks for your time

Answer (score -1):

My main activity extends **Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

In this activity i was trying to to move to another that it was extending **AppCombatActivity** class.

```
public class FuelChoiceActivity extends AppCombatActivity
```

so the syntax and all is right. So i changed the FuelChoiceActivity(the activity i desired to move at) extend to :

```
public class FuelChoiceActivity extends Activity
```

Seems like you cannot move to another activity if they both dont extend the same class.

Comment: Not for my sake, but for future reader's sake, please explain in details what exactly you did, and what "the same class is".